# SSRS 2008 problem with Date type parameter

Tags: service, reporting

I want to specify a report parameter with Data Type: **Date/Time**
When I Specify a value manually like 14.07.2011 00:00:00 , the report run as expected but when I "Get a value from a query" ( Stored Procedure returning  the date as follows: 14.07.2011 00:00:00  I got the error : The property 'ValidValues' of a report paameter 'Date1' doesn't have the expected type...

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tried against AdventureWorks2008 database.

Data set 1 is from SalesOrderHeader. Data set 2 is Select distinct OrderDate from SalesOrderHeader. I create a parameter OrderDate that has values from Data set 2. Then add Data set 1 with "WHERE OrderDate = @OrderDate". It works for me.

I think as long as your stored procedure returns a DateTime column, you are fine. You may want to check the **data type** there.

Hope this helps.